# Python for loop change the type of original data halfway

Tags: python

I'm working with a .csv file that contains unix timestamp and I'm trying to convert every unix timestamp into a datetime instance.

```
import csv 
import datetime 

def count(month, data):
    month_count = 0
    for row in data[1:]: 
        # print(type(row[2]),row[2]) # This is for review
        float_num = float(row[2])
        row[2] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float_num)
        if row[2].month == month:
            month_count += 1
    return month_count

with open('askreddit_2015.csv') as file: 
    posts = list(csv.reader(file)) # posts is a list of lists

feb_count = count(2, posts)
aug_count = count(8, posts)

print(feb_count)
print(aug_count)
```

The row[2] of the .csv file looks like

```
1433213314
1434205517
1443409636
1440188623
1440082910
```

When I run my original code, I got `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'`, which is weird because all the data in row[2] are originally string. To check where is the problem, I added that review line and when I run, I got

```
<class 'str'> 1433213314
<class 'str'> 1434205517
<class 'str'> 1443409636
<class 'str'> 1440188623
<class 'str'> 1440082910
<class 'datetime.datetime'> 2015-06-01 19:48:34
```

with `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'`Why does my code try to put a already converted row[2] value back to float() again? Shouldn't the iteration already finished at that point? Thanks.

Comment: You're calling `count` twice. The first time you are altering the data in `rows` in place. The second call is seeing the altered data where you have set `row[2] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float_num)`

Comment: @MarkMeyer I think I get what you're saying, but shouldn't a local manipulation has no influence on a global variable?

Comment: The local variable `data` is a reference to `posts`, not a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the original array in the `count()` function.

You could simply check whether the element containing the date is a string before trying to convert it.

```
def count(month, data):
    month_count = 0
    for row in data[1:]:
        if isinstance(row[s], str):
            row[2] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(row[2]))
        if row[2].month = month:
            month_count += 1
    return month_count
```

Comment: All 5 data is a string and I don't know why my print() yields 6 results, where the last one is a datetime.

Comment: The first 5 strings are from the first call to `count()`. The second call prints `<class 'datetime.datetime'> 2015-06-01 19:48:34` then stops because of the error.